# To generate a random number by using time

Tags: haskell

I would like to generate a number by using `Data.Time.Clock.POSIT`

```
test' = do
    y <- getPOSIXTime
    let w =  (tail (take 3 (reverse(show y))))
    return w

 test2 = do 
     getseed <- test'
     let x = read (getseed)
     putStrLn (show(x))
```

So I use `getPOSIXTime` to get time with the nanosecond, so I convert it into a string and take the first 3 digits and then convert them back to Int.  However, it gives me error like this:

```
test.hs:156:14: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘read’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Read a0)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include x :: a0 (bound at test.hs:156:10)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Read GeneralCategory -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
        instance Read Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
        instance Read Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
        ...plus 23 others
        ...plus 12 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: read (getseed)
      In an equation for ‘x’: x = read (getseed)
      In the expression:
        do getseed <- test'
           let x = read (getseed)
           putStrLn (show (x))
    |
156 |      let x = read (getseed)
    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

test.hs:157:16: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘show’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include x :: a0 (bound at test.hs:156:10)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show GeneralCategory -- Defined in ‘GHC.Unicode’
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 23 others
        ...plus 27 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely ‘(show (x))’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn (show (x))
      In the expression:
        do getseed <- test'
           let x = read (getseed)
           putStrLn (show (x))
    |
157 |      putStrLn (show(x))
    |                ^^^^^^^
```

any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Even though `show (read x))` may *seem* like it is equivalent to `id x`, it is not to the type checker. You need to give *some* type to `x`.

Comment: It works, you are a star!!!